# CSS First Child Select, with special class omission

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm doing rounded corners on the top and bottom of a list, and each LI has a background color. Because of the background color the rounded corners for the entire UL don't apply, and the first and last LI still have square corners.

Everything is fine, except there are scenarios where the first LI actually needs to be hidden,  and I do this with a class name, in the example below I have "hide-me".

```
<ul>
   <li class="hide-me">A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

So in the code above I'd like to hide the LI with the class "hide-me" and on show LI B,C,D. So LI B would have rounded top left and top right, and LI D would have rounded bottom left and rounded bottom right.

The CSS I'm using is like:

```
li:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

li:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

li { background:yellow; }

.hide-me { display:none; }
```

But as you can see, my above CSS would apply the rounded corners to the LI A that's hidden. But in this case LI B would on top of the list because LI A is hidden, but since its not the first child in the UL it doesn't have the rounded corners.

So for this scenario, how do I apply rounded corners for the first LI that's not hidden?

Comment: Seems tricky, anything against just setting a class on the 2nd item (first li not hidden)? Shouldn't be too hard to, when setting the first item to hidden, using jQuery (or .net/php) to add a class to the next item.  In CSS3 there is the :nth-child(2) psuedo selector, but not fully supported everywhere yet (aka IE :).

Comment: Why didn't they create a :first-matching pseudo selector? It seems most of the pseudo selectors are only useful if you're not applying other classes to the elements.

Comment: Have you tried placing the border-radius on the unordered list and using overflow: hidden;?

Comment: Overflow:hidden trick doesn't work. It's probably because I'm actually using background gradients, not just a solid color like I used in my quick example.

Comment: @animuson: They're working on an [`:nth-match()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#nth-match) right now, so in theory one could use `li:not(.hide_me):nth-match(1)`. But yeah, they should've come up with it ages ago...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
li:first-child,
li.hide-me:first-child + li {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Also, would simply using this work?

```
ul {
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the overflow:hidden trick and it doesn't work. But the adjacent element idea is a good one, thanks.

Comment: This won't work if you have more than one hidden element before the first non-hidden one, however.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the first selector to `li:first-child, .hide-me:first-child + li`.

So, select the first child if it's an `li`, or select an `li` preceded by an element with a class of `.hide-me` if it's the first child.